# Importing email addresses into AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm using a powershell script to try to import email addresses into Active Directory. Here is the script I'm using (full disclosure, I copied this from another post on this site):

```
Import-module ActiveDirectory
$Users = Import-CSV "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\HPD_Users.csv"
ForEach($User in $Users) 
{
    Set-ADUser -Identity $User.UserName -EmailAddress $User.Email
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Set-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity: 'Smith, John' under: 'DC=abc,DC=wxyz,DC=com'.
At C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Import_AD_Email.ps1:5 char:5
+     Set-ADUser -Identity $User.UserName -EmailAddress $User.Email
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Smith, John:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetAD 
   User
```

I think the issue is that we have the users in a specific OU. How do I specify that in the script?

Comment: The issue seems to be that `$user.UserName` contains the users `DisplayName` (seems like) not theirs `sAMAccountName`. Can you confirm that?

Answer (score 0):

Like Santiago mentioned, looks like the issue here is that `$User.UserName` is actually the `DisplayName` attribute in Active Directory.

The best and most performant way to do this would be to run it against the `sAMAccountName` - but if all you have access to is the `DisplayName` in your CSV, you could try something along these lines instead;

```
Import-module ActiveDirectory
$Users = Import-CSV "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\HPD_Users.csv"

ForEach($User in $Users) 
{
    $ADUser = Get-ADUser -Filter { DisplayName -like $User.UserName } -Properties DisplayName
    Write-Host "Updating email for [$($ADUser.DisplayName)] to [$($User.Email)]"
    #Set-ADUser $ADUser -EmailAddress $User.Email -WhatIf
}
```

Comment: OK, I tried this suggestion, and it's still not working, but generating a different error:

Comment: Get-ADUser : Property: 'DisplayName' not found in object of type: 'System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject'.
At C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Import_AD_Email_v2.ps1:6 char:15
+ ...   $ADUser = Get-ADUser -Filter { DisplayName -like $User.DisplayName  ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADUser], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
 
Updating email for [] to [john.smith@abc.com]

Comment: Try updating the `Get-ADUser` line to this instead;

`$ADUser = Get-ADUser -Filter { DisplayName -like $User.UserName } -Properties DisplayName`

I don't have it handy to test right now, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work using sAMAccountName. Here was my final script:

```
Import-module ActiveDirectory
$Users = Import-CSV "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\HPD_Users3.csv"
ForEach($User in $Users) 
{
    Set-ADUser -Identity $User.sAMAccountName -EmailAddress $User.Email
}
```

And my CSV file looked like this:

```
Email,sAMAccountName 
john.smith@abc.com,jsmith 
jane.doe@abc.com,jdoe
```